# pushd \\network\path returns CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories

Tags: windows, cmd

I was using a batch file to access some files from network.

I am using

```
pushd \\Network\path
```

to navigate to the networked directory to initiate some scripts

My bat file was working perfectly fine till this morning I saw "cmd returning CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories".

I have seen this error message when using cd instead of pushd to navigate to a network directory but I can figure out why I am getting error for a previously working bat file.

And I did make sure that network location was online and accessible other way round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `pushd /?`:

> If command extensions are enabled the PUSHD command accepts network
>   paths in addition to the normal drive letter and path. If a network
>   path is specified, PUSHD will create a temporary drive letter that
>   points to the specified network resource and then change the current
>   drive and directory.

Do any mapped drives show up in `net use` after `pushd` is executed?

If you're not getting some kind of network authorization error, make sure command extensions are enabled (I'm not sure why they wouldn't be.)

`cmd /x` will enable extensions for the current CMD session. Try that prior to executing your batch script.

The "main switch" is in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`.
`EnableExtensions` should be `(DWORD) 1`

Answer (score 12):

Be sure to also check that you haven't just run out of drive letters. If you have a rogue script that isn't using popd after it's done with the drive, or is crashing before it gets to popd, you can end up with a bunch of garbage mapped drive. Easy to check as they'll show up in `net use` and "My Computer". For some reason cmd will give this cryptic error (`CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.`) instead of telling you it ran out of drives to map to.